# How to create a custom realm file

Tags: ios, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm initializing my realm instance like so:

```
private static let sUserRealm:Realm = try! Realm(configuration:Realm.Configuration(
        fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "user" ,withExtension: "realm"),
        inMemoryIdentifier: nil,
        syncConfiguration: nil,
        encryptionKey: nil,
        readOnly: false,
        schemaVersion: 0,
        migrationBlock: sMigrationBlock,
        deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true,
        objectTypes: nil))
```

However, I'm gettting this error:

```
fatal error: A Realm Configuration must specify a path or an in-memory 
identifier.: file /Users/realm/workspace/Package iOS Swift/tightdb_objc/RealmSwift/RealmConfiguration.swift, line 201
```

All realm has in their swift documentation about creating multiple realms is [this](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#other-realms) example, and even copying it verbatim throws the same error. How do I create and access the realm file?

Answer (score 7):

***Swift 5:***

Simply custom your realm file's name

```
struct Kingdom {
    static let persist = Kingdom()

    let realm: Realm = { () -> Realm in
        var config = Realm.Configuration()
        config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("deng.realm")
        let land = try! Realm(configuration: config)
        return land
    }()
}
```

---

custom your realm file's name and path

```
struct Kingdom {
    static let persist = Kingdom()

    let realm: Realm = { () -> Realm in
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        let docURL = URL(string: documentsDirectory)!
        let dataPath = docURL.appendingPathComponent("Dng")
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString) == false{
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        do {
            var config = Realm.Configuration()
            config.fileURL = dataPath.appendingPathComponent("deng.realm")
            let realmReal = try Realm(configuration: config)
            return realmReal
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            let realmForSyntax = try! Realm()
            return realmForSyntax
        }
    }()
}
```

[image: 111]

Answer (score 5):

`Bundle.url(forResource:withExtension:)` returns the path to an *existing* file within a given bundle. The portion of the Realm documentation that you link to uses the example of including a Realm file within your app bundle.

Since it looks like you're attempting to create a *new* Realm file at a specific path, you should compute that path and set it as the `fileURL` on the `Realm.Configuration`. You typically do not want to use `Bundle` APIs for that as files within your app's bundle are not writeable. Instead you should construct a path relative to your app's document or cache directory:

```
let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask,
                                                appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let url = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("my-new-realm.realm")
```

Comment: but if you include a realm file within your app bundle, [won't it be read only](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5026133/6744473)?

Comment: Yes? If you have a Realm file in your app bundle that you want to write to, you need to first copy it to somewhere that's writable. If you're not working with a Realm file that was included as part of your app bundle, construct a path that points to the document or cache directory instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample Realm configuration class, each configuration create a new Realm file.

```
     import Foundation
     import RealmSwift

     class RealmConfiguration {

// Create "default.realm" in document file
        public static var defaultDataConfiguration = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration

// Create "insensitive.realm"
        static func insensitiveDataConfiguration() -> Realm.Configuration {
            var config = Realm.Configuration()
            config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("insensitive.realm")
            return config
        }

// Create "sensitive.realm"
        static func sensitiveDataConfiguration() -> Realm.Configuration {
            var config = Realm.Configuration()
            config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("sensitive.realm")
            return config
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used this But non of them will not work in today extension

Comment: I don't have error actually when I use this it will work but only in the app and in the extension I can not access that file and it treat like there is no file

Comment: I'll need to see code, I don't have idea about your problem.

Comment: I can give you access in team viewer to see my codes if you want

Comment: No, I do't have enough time, excuse me, ask a new question and share it here, or put your code here

Answer (score 0):

use 
`Bundle.main.url(forResource: "user" ,withExtension: "realm")!` but this value might be `nil` because of your file doesn't exist

instead of 
`Bundle.main.url(forResource: "user" ,withExtension: "realm")`

be careful and setup

**EDIT**

To use predefined database you can use `Bundle` .

But if you want to use new database for your app, use the other path. Not bundle.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

```
var config = Realm.Configuration()

  // Use the default directory, but replace the filename with the username
  config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent()
                         .appendingPathComponent("\(username).realm")
```

than

`sUserRealm:Realm = try! Realm(configuration:config)`

or any path you want but not `Bundle` .

to create and edit files and directories:

```
let fileManager:FileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentdir:String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last!

        let dbName = someDataBaseFileName

        let yourFullFileName = String(format:"%@/%@",documentdir,dbName)
```

//or

```
let yourFullPath:String = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentdir).appendingPathComponent(dbName).path
```

Comment: `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "user" ,withExtension: "realm")` returns nil, so  it throws an error

Comment: so, that 's an answer. you feed `Realm` by `nil` value.

Comment: not an answer. the question is "how do i create and access the realm file?" the fact that we now know that i feed realm a nil value doesn't satisfy that question